# Git Bash make all command failing

Tags: java, compilation, package, gnu-make, git-bash

I am new to these things so excuse me if my question is dumb.

I am trying to install a Emulator software on my windows 11 pc but the software comes as a makefile like directory and the instuctions told me to install it with git bash. But no matter what I did I couldnt get it to work as intended. The make all command keeps throwing the errors shown below to me.

```
C:\Users\arday\rp2040pio>make all
cd ./java ; make -f Makefile.Server all
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/arday/rp2040pio/java'
javac -Xlint:all -Xdiags:verbose -d ../build/EmulationServer -cp ../java:../build/EmulationServer ../java/org/soundpaint/rp2040pio/EmulationServer.java
warning: [path] Invalid filename: ../java:../build/EmulationServer
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:37: error: package CmdOptions does not exist
  private static final CmdOptions.FlagOptionDeclaration optVersion =
                                 ^
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:40: error: package CmdOptions does not exist
  private static final CmdOptions.FlagOptionDeclaration optHelp =
                                 ^
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:43: error: package CmdOptions does not exist
  private static final CmdOptions.FlagOptionDeclaration optSilent =
                                 ^
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:46: error: package CmdOptions does not exist
  private static final CmdOptions.FlagOptionDeclaration optVerbose =
                                 ^
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:49: error: package CmdOptions does not exist
  private static final CmdOptions.IntegerOptionDeclaration optPort =
                                 ^
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:54: error: package CmdOptions does not exist
  private static final List<CmdOptions.OptionDeclaration<?>>
                                      ^
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
  private final CmdOptions options;
                ^
  symbol:   class CmdOptions
  location: class EmulationServer
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
  private CmdOptions parseArgs(final String argv[])
          ^
  symbol:   class CmdOptions
  location: class EmulationServer
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:101: error: cannot find symbol
  private void checkValidity(final CmdOptions options)
                                   ^
  symbol:   class CmdOptions
  location: class EmulationServer
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:102: error: package CmdOptions does not exist
    throws CmdOptions.ParseException
                     ^
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:38: error: package CmdOptions does not exist
    CmdOptions.createFlagOption(false, 'V', "version", CmdOptions.Flag.OFF,
                                                                 ^
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
    CmdOptions.createFlagOption(false, 'V', "version", CmdOptions.Flag.OFF,
    ^
  symbol:   variable CmdOptions
  location: class EmulationServer
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:41: error: package CmdOptions does not exist
    CmdOptions.createFlagOption(false, 'h', "help", CmdOptions.Flag.OFF,
                                                              ^
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
    CmdOptions.createFlagOption(false, 'h', "help", CmdOptions.Flag.OFF,
    ^
  symbol:   variable CmdOptions
  location: class EmulationServer
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:44: error: package CmdOptions does not exist
    CmdOptions.createFlagOption(false, 's', "silent", CmdOptions.Flag.OFF,
                                                                ^
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
    CmdOptions.createFlagOption(false, 's', "silent", CmdOptions.Flag.OFF,
    ^
  symbol:   variable CmdOptions
  location: class EmulationServer
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:47: error: package CmdOptions does not exist
    CmdOptions.createFlagOption(false, 'v', "verbose", CmdOptions.Flag.OFF,
                                                                 ^
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
    CmdOptions.createFlagOption(false, 'v', "verbose", CmdOptions.Flag.OFF,
    ^
  symbol:   variable CmdOptions
  location: class EmulationServer
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
                                   Constants.
                                   ^
  symbol:   variable Constants
  location: class EmulationServer
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
    CmdOptions.createIntegerOption("PORT", false, 'p', "port",
    ^
  symbol:   variable CmdOptions
  location: class EmulationServer
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:56: error: package CmdOptions does not exist
    Arrays.asList(new CmdOptions.OptionDeclaration<?>[]
                                ^
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:69: error: package CmdOptions does not exist
    if (options.getValue(optSilent) != CmdOptions.Flag.ON) {
                                                 ^
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
    final CmdOptions options;
          ^
  symbol:   class CmdOptions
  location: class EmulationServer
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:78: error: cannot find symbol
      options = new CmdOptions(PRG_TITLE, PRG_FULL_NAME, null,
                    ^
  symbol:   class CmdOptions
  location: class EmulationServer
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:82: error: package CmdOptions does not exist
    } catch (final CmdOptions.ParseException e) {
                             ^
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:87: error: package CmdOptions does not exist
    if (options.getValue(optVersion) == CmdOptions.Flag.ON) {
                                                  ^
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:89: error: cannot find symbol
      console.println(Constants.getEmulatorIdAndVersionWithOs());
                      ^
  symbol:   variable Constants
  location: class EmulationServer
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:93: error: package CmdOptions does not exist
    if (options.getValue(optHelp) == CmdOptions.Flag.ON) {
                                               ^
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:106: error: package CmdOptions does not exist
      throw new CmdOptions.
                          ^
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:109: error: package CmdOptions does not exist
    if ((options.getValue(optSilent) == CmdOptions.Flag.ON) &&
                                                  ^
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:110: error: package CmdOptions does not exist
        (options.getValue(optVerbose) == CmdOptions.Flag.ON)) {
                                                   ^
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:111: error: package CmdOptions does not exist
      throw new CmdOptions.
                          ^
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:120: error: cannot find symbol
                   Constants.getEmulatorIdAndVersionWithOs(),
                   ^
  symbol:   variable Constants
  location: class EmulationServer
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:121: error: cannot find symbol
                   Constants.getCmdLineCopyrightNotice());
                   ^
  symbol:   variable Constants
  location: class EmulationServer
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:127: error: cannot find symbol
      final Emulator emulator = new Emulator(console);
            ^
  symbol:   class Emulator
  location: class EmulationServer
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:127: error: cannot find symbol
      final Emulator emulator = new Emulator(console);
                                    ^
  symbol:   class Emulator
  location: class EmulationServer
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:128: error: cannot find symbol
      final LocalAddressSpace memory = new LocalAddressSpace(emulator);
            ^
  symbol:   class LocalAddressSpace
  location: class EmulationServer
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:128: error: cannot find symbol
      final LocalAddressSpace memory = new LocalAddressSpace(emulator);
                                           ^
  symbol:   class LocalAddressSpace
  location: class EmulationServer
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:130: error: cannot find symbol
      final RemoteAddressSpaceServer server =
            ^
  symbol:   class RemoteAddressSpaceServer
  location: class EmulationServer
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:131: error: cannot find symbol
        new RemoteAddressSpaceServer(console, memory, port);
            ^
  symbol:   class RemoteAddressSpaceServer
  location: class EmulationServer
..\java\org\soundpaint\rp2040pio\EmulationServer.java:132: error: package CmdOptions does not exist
      if (options.getValue(optSilent) != CmdOptions.Flag.ON) {
                                                   ^
41 errors
1 warning
make[1]: *** [Makefile.Server:98: ../build/EmulationServer/org/soundpaint/rp2040pio/EmulationServer.class] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/arday/rp2040pio/java'
make: *** [Makefile:28: all] Error 2
```

MAKEFILE

```
ROOT_DIR=.
include defs.mak

all:
    cd $(JAVA_DIR) ; make -f Makefile.Server all
    cd $(JAVA_DIR) ; make -f Makefile.Monitor all
    cd $(JAVA_DIR) ; make -f Makefile.Observer all
    cd $(JAVA_DIR) ; make -f Makefile.Diagram all
    cd $(JAVA_DIR) ; make -f Makefile.GPIOObserver all
    cd $(JAVA_DIR) ; make -f Makefile.CodeObserver all
    cd $(JAVA_DIR) ; make -f Makefile.FifoObserver all
    cd $(JAVA_DIR) ; make -f Makefile.DocTool all

run: all
    cd $(JAVA_DIR) ; make -f Makefile.Server run

tags:
    - find $(JAVA_DIR) -name \*.java -exec etags {} \; -print

objclean:
    rm -rf $(ROOT_BUILD_DIR)
    rm -rf $(JAR_DIR)
    rm -rf $(RST_DOC_DIR)

bkpclean:
    - find $(JAVA_DIR) -name \*~ -exec /bin/rm -f {} \; -print
    rm -f *~

coreclean:
    rm -f core core.* vgcore.*
    rm -f $(JAVA_DIR)/core $(JAVA_DIR)/core.* $(JAVA_DIR)/vgcore.*

clean: objclean

distclean: objclean bkpclean coreclean

tarball: distclean
    @TGZ_DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S` ; \
    PROJECT_NAME=rpi2040pio ; \
    PROJECT_PATH=`basename \`pwd\`` ; \
    TGZ_PREFIX=$$PROJECT_NAME\_$$TGZ_DATE ; cd .. ; \
    tar cvf ./$$TGZ_PREFIX.tar.bz2 \
        --exclude=untracked \
        --exclude=.git \
        --transform=s/$$PROJECT_PATH/$$TGZ_PREFIX/ \
        --bzip2 $$PROJECT_PATH
```

Makefile.server

```
ROOT_DIR=..
include ../defs.mak

BUILD_DIR=$(ROOT_BUILD_DIR)/EmulationServer
COMPILE_CLASSPATH=$(JAVA_DIR):$(BUILD_DIR)
RUN_CLASSPATH=.
PIO_DIR=$(JAVA_DIR)/org/soundpaint/rp2040pio
JAVA_SRC=$(wildcard $(PIO_DIR)/EmulationServer.java)
JAVA_OBJ=$(patsubst $(JAVA_DIR)/%.java,$(BUILD_DIR)/%.class,$(JAVA_SRC))

MEDIA_SRC_DIR=$(JAVA_DIR)/media
MEDIA_OBJ_DIR=$(BUILD_DIR)/media
MEDIA_SRC=$(wildcard $(MEDIA_SRC_DIR)/*.png $(MEDIA_SRC_DIR)/*.html)
MEDIA_OBJ=$(patsubst $(MEDIA_SRC_DIR)/%,$(MEDIA_OBJ_DIR)/%,$(MEDIA_SRC))

EXAMPLES_SRC_DIR=$(JAVA_DIR)/examples
EXAMPLES_OBJ_DIR=$(BUILD_DIR)/examples
EXAMPLES_SRC=$(wildcard $(EXAMPLES_SRC_DIR)/*.hex) $(wildcard $(EXAMPLES_SRC_DIR)/*.mon)
EXAMPLES_OBJ=$(patsubst $(EXAMPLES_SRC_DIR)/%,$(EXAMPLES_OBJ_DIR)/%,$(EXAMPLES_SRC))

JAR_OBJ=$(JAR_DIR)/rp2040pio_server.jar

all: obj jar

obj: $(BUILD_DIR) $(JAVA_OBJ) \
    $(MEDIA_OBJ_DIR) $(MEDIA_OBJ) \
    $(EXAMPLES_OBJ_DIR) $(EXAMPLES_OBJ)

$(BUILD_DIR):
    mkdir -p $@

$(MEDIA_OBJ_DIR):
    echo BUILD_MEDIA_DIR=$(MEDIA_OBJ_DIR)
    mkdir -p $@

$(EXAMPLES_OBJ_DIR):
    echo BUILD_EXAMPLES_DIR=$(EXAMPLES_OBJ_DIR)
    mkdir -p $@

$(JAR_DIR):
    mkdir -p $@

jar: $(JAR_DIR) $(JAR_OBJ)

$(JAR_OBJ): $(JAVA_OBJ)
    cd $(BUILD_DIR) ; \
    jar -0cvfm ../$(JAR_OBJ) ../$(JAVA_DIR)/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF.Server .

$(MEDIA_OBJ_DIR)/%: $(MEDIA_SRC_DIR)/%
    cp -pf $< $@

$(EXAMPLES_OBJ_DIR)/%.hex: $(EXAMPLES_SRC_DIR)/%.hex
    cp -pf $< $@

$(EXAMPLES_OBJ_DIR)/%.mon: $(EXAMPLES_SRC_DIR)/%.mon
    cp -pf $< $@

depend:

run: all
    cd $(JAR_DIR) ; java -jar $(JAR_OBJ)
    #cd $(BUILD_DIR) ; java -ea -cp $(RUN_CLASSPATH) org.soundpaint.rp2040pio.Main

objclean:
    - rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)

jarclean:
    - rm -rf $(JAR_DIR)

clean: objclean jarclean

.SUFFIXES: $(SUFFIXES) .java .class

$(BUILD_DIR)%class: $(JAVA_DIR)%java
    javac -Xlint:all -Xdiags:verbose -d $(BUILD_DIR) -cp $(COMPILE_CLASSPATH) $<
```

I don't have much knowledge about this compiling your own app thing so all i did to try to solve it was google it online which didn't help much and make sure everything was up to date

Comment: `warning: [path] Invalid filename: ../java:../build/EmulationServer` which means your makefile is specifying the classpath wrong.  You're still running under windows, so the classpath separator is `;`, not `:`.

Comment: Hi I just edited the post to include the makefile can you take a look if you have the time because only ":" I saw was on the "header" like things which I dont think are the ones

Comment: It's right here: `COMPILE_CLASSPATH=$(JAVA_DIR):$(BUILD_DIR)`  In general you usually can't just take a makefile written for a POSIX system and run it on Windows, without changes.  Windows is too different.

Comment: Well no luck.. I decided to throw this idea all together and use VirtualBox and DebianOS.. It worked much easier. Thanks anyways for your help <3